# Liquibase not working from within JBoss?

Tags: liquibase

I am using Liquibase 3.3.2 and trying to implement a webservice that accepts a number of changelogs, looks up a specific DataSource depending on the context, and use that DataSource together with the liquibase ChangeLogs to perform a database update.

I am using PostgreSQL as a database.

Somehow the liquibase logging from the webservice side indicates no problem at all, all seems to be executing correctly. However, no tables appear in the database, not even Liquibase's own lock/state tables..

This is the logging of the webservice with Liquibase's debug logging enabled:

```
14:09:11,918 INFO  [nl.minienm.standaardplatform.databasemanager.DatabaseManager] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) Parsing with class liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser
14:09:12,385 INFO  [nl.minienm.standaardplatform.databasemanager.DatabaseManager] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) Obtaining Connection...
14:09:12,385 INFO  [nl.minienm.standaardplatform.databasemanager.configuration.ConfigurationLoaderConfigurationProviderImpl] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) Looking up JNDI datasource for application 'StandaardPlatformReferentieImpl'
14:09:12,410 INFO  [nl.minienm.standaardplatform.databasemanager.configuration.ConfigurationLoaderConfigurationProviderImpl] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) Application datasource java:jboss/datasources/referentieimplDS
14:09:12,413 INFO  [nl.minienm.standaardplatform.databasemanager.DatabaseManager] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) Connection Obtained. AC=false SCHEMADEFAULT=public 
14:09:12,440 INFO  [nl.minienm.standaardplatform.databasemanager.DatabaseManager] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) Running Liquibase on ChangeLog /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml
14:09:12,458 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) DEBUG 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: Created database lock table with name: public.databasechangeloglock
14:09:12,459 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) DEBUG 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from public.databasechangeloglock
14:09:12,464 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) INFO 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
14:09:12,467 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) INFO 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: Creating database history table with name: public.databasechangelog
14:09:12,469 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) DEBUG 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from public.databasechangeloglock
14:09:12,483 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) DEBUG 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.0::sander: Running Changeset:/tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.0::sander
14:09:12,485 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) DEBUG 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.0::sander: Reading ChangeSet: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.0::sander
14:09:12,486 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) DEBUG 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.0::sander: Executing Statement: liquibase.statement.core.CreateTableStatement@e35392a
14:09:12,486 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) INFO 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.0::sander: Table Persoon created
14:09:12,486 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) INFO 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.0::sander: ChangeSet /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.0::sander ran successfully in 2ms
14:09:12,488 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) DEBUG 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.0::sander: Executing QUERY database command: SELECT MAX(ORDEREXECUTED) FROM public.databasechangelog
14:09:12,491 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) DEBUG 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.0::sander: Computed checksum for createTable:[
14:09:12,492 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)     columns=[
14:09:12,492 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)         [
14:09:12,492 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)             [
14:09:12,492 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)                 nullable="true"
14:09:12,492 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)                 primaryKey="false"
14:09:12,492 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)                 unique="false"
14:09:12,493 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)             ]
14:09:12,493 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)             name="Voornaam"
14:09:12,493 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)             type="varchar(64)"
14:09:12,493 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)         ]
14:09:12,493 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)     ]
14:09:12,493 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)     tableName="Persoon"
14:09:12,494 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) ] as 69c496bed203364c2bcf0d96b3cd03ae
14:09:12,494 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) DEBUG 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.0::sander: Computed checksum for 7:69c496bed203364c2bcf0d96b3cd03ae: as 7723e55b38281ea28fc0d01a060bc8ad
14:09:12,497 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) DEBUG 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.0::sander: Computed checksum for createTable:[
14:09:12,497 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)     columns=[
14:09:12,498 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)         [
14:09:12,498 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)             [
14:09:12,498 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)                 nullable="true"
14:09:12,498 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)                 primaryKey="false"
14:09:12,498 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)                 unique="false"
14:09:12,498 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)             ]
14:09:12,499 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)             name="Voornaam"
14:09:12,499 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)             type="varchar(64)"
14:09:12,499 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)         ]
14:09:12,499 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)     ]
14:09:12,499 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)     tableName="Persoon"
14:09:12,499 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) ] as 69c496bed203364c2bcf0d96b3cd03ae
14:09:12,500 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) DEBUG 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.0::sander: Computed checksum for 7:69c496bed203364c2bcf0d96b3cd03ae: as 7723e55b38281ea28fc0d01a060bc8ad
14:09:12,508 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) DEBUG 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.1::sander: Running Changeset:/tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.1::sander
14:09:12,510 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) DEBUG 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.1::sander: Reading ChangeSet: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.1::sander
14:09:12,510 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) DEBUG 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.1::sander: Executing Statement: liquibase.statement.core.CreateTableStatement@6a1b9b89
14:09:12,511 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) INFO 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.1::sander: Table mytable created
14:09:12,511 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) INFO 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.1::sander: ChangeSet /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.1::sander ran successfully in 3ms
14:09:12,512 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) DEBUG 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.1::sander: Computed checksum for createTable:[
14:09:12,512 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)     columns=[
14:09:12,512 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)         [
14:09:12,512 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)             [
14:09:12,512 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)                 nullable="true"
14:09:12,513 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)                 primaryKey="false"
14:09:12,513 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)                 unique="false"
14:09:12,513 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)             ]
14:09:12,513 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)             name="teller"
14:09:12,513 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)             type="int"
14:09:12,513 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)         ]
14:09:12,514 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)     ]
14:09:12,514 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)     tableName="mytable"
14:09:12,514 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) ] as 2297ed7210f5e9b39e7b007c4067500f
14:09:12,514 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) DEBUG 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.1::sander: Computed checksum for 7:2297ed7210f5e9b39e7b007c4067500f: as e7ad573879c5874b948897438bee1f5a
14:09:12,516 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) DEBUG 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.1::sander: Computed checksum for createTable:[
14:09:12,516 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)     columns=[
14:09:12,516 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)         [
14:09:12,516 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)             [
14:09:12,517 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)                 nullable="true"
14:09:12,517 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)                 primaryKey="false"
14:09:12,517 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)                 unique="false"
14:09:12,517 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)             ]
14:09:12,517 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)             name="teller"
14:09:12,517 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)             type="int"
14:09:12,518 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)         ]
14:09:12,518 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)     ]
14:09:12,518 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2)     tableName="mytable"
14:09:12,518 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) ] as 2297ed7210f5e9b39e7b007c4067500f
14:09:12,518 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) DEBUG 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml: /tmp/tmp1005363315409204/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.1::sander: Computed checksum for 7:2297ed7210f5e9b39e7b007c4067500f: as e7ad573879c5874b948897438bee1f5a
14:09:12,519 ERROR [stderr] (ajp-SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2/172.31.115.228:8009-2) INFO 2/27/15 2:09 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
```

PostgreSQL's log only shows :

```
< 2015-02-27 13:50:16.622 CET >ERROR:  relation "public.databasechangeloglock" does not exist at character 22
< 2015-02-27 13:50:16.622 CET >STATEMENT:  select count(*) from public.databasechangeloglock
< 2015-02-27 13:50:16.632 CET >ERROR:  relation "public.databasechangeloglock" does not exist at character 22
< 2015-02-27 13:50:16.632 CET >STATEMENT:  select count(*) from public.databasechangeloglock
< 2015-02-27 13:50:16.653 CET >ERROR:  relation "public.databasechangelog" does not exist at character 32
< 2015-02-27 13:50:16.653 CET >STATEMENT:  SELECT MAX(ORDEREXECUTED) FROM public.databasechangelog
```

If I pass a Writer object to Liquibase.update(), it gets filled with correct SQL that I can manually execute, with desired result, from pgAdmin, so I know it doesn't generate invalid SQL:

```
-- *********************************************************************
-- Update Database Script
-- *********************************************************************
-- Change Log: /tmp/tmp8746853329558673/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml
-- Ran at: 2/27/15 2:17 PM
-- Against: referentieimplDBUser@jdbc:postgresql://sp-tst-green-prd-server1.kernteamcloud.nl/referentieimplDB
-- Liquibase version: 3.3.2
-- *********************************************************************

-- Create Database Lock Table
CREATE TABLE public.databasechangeloglock (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID));

-- Initialize Database Lock Table
DELETE FROM public.databasechangeloglock;

INSERT INTO public.databasechangeloglock (ID, LOCKED) VALUES (1, FALSE);

-- Lock Database
UPDATE public.databasechangeloglock SET LOCKED = TRUE, LOCKEDBY = 'SP-TST-Orange-PRD-Server2 (172.31.115.228)', LOCKGRANTED = '2015-02-27 14:17:01.121' WHERE ID = 1 AND LOCKED = FALSE;

-- Create Database Change Log Table
CREATE TABLE public.databasechangelog (ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, AUTHOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, FILENAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, DATEEXECUTED TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL, ORDEREXECUTED INT NOT NULL, EXECTYPE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, MD5SUM VARCHAR(35), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255), COMMENTS VARCHAR(255), TAG VARCHAR(255), LIQUIBASE VARCHAR(20));

-- Changeset /tmp/tmp8746853329558673/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.0::sander
CREATE TABLE public."Persoon" ("Voornaam" VARCHAR(64));

INSERT INTO public.databasechangelog (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, LIQUIBASE) VALUES ('1.0.0', 'sander', '/tmp/tmp8746853329558673/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml', NOW(), 1, '7:7723e55b38281ea28fc0d01a060bc8ad', 'createTable', '', 'EXECUTED', '3.3.2');

-- Changeset /tmp/tmp8746853329558673/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml::1.0.1::sander
CREATE TABLE public.mytable (teller INT);

INSERT INTO public.databasechangelog (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, LIQUIBASE) VALUES ('1.0.1', 'sander', '/tmp/tmp8746853329558673/blah/tmp/test/changelog-001.xml', NOW(), 2, '7:e7ad573879c5874b948897438bee1f5a', 'createTable', '', 'EXECUTED', '3.3.2');

-- Release Database Lock
UPDATE public.databasechangeloglock SET LOCKED = FALSE, LOCKEDBY = NULL, LOCKGRANTED = NULL WHERE ID = 1;
```

What am I missing here? Is there a missing commit? Something wrong with my DataSource? Some (un)set state inside Liquibase?

Comment: At least creating the `public.databasechangelog` should work. Are you a 100% sure you're looking at the same database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause pretty soon after posting the question here, so to answer my own question:

Passing a Writer object to Liquibase does capture the generated SQL to that Writer, but also **prevents** it from being sent to the database.

So simply not passing a Writer object actually makes the SQL go to the database, in which case it all works as it should.

This behaviour is not documented, nor is it immediately clear from the source.